# Reading last login date from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I am storing last login date from session in database. Database is taking the correct value from the session.

Can you please help me to get the exact last login date on my UI label?

I am doing as follows, but it is taking present value because I am again reading from session. To prevent this how and where should I define last login date?

```
public string lastLoginDate = "";

DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(userInfoModel.LastLoginDate, "yyyyMMdd",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
lastLoginDate = (dt.Month + "/" + dt.Day + "/" + dt.Year).ToString();
```

Comment: Could you post the code that creates the `userInfoModel` object?

Comment: userInfoModel = OLB.Cust.Helpers.SessionManager.Get<UserInfoModel>("UserInfoModel");

Comment: @laylarenee ...I am reading the value of session again. Thats why it is reading from current session. Right? To prevent this, what I should do?

Comment: It sounds like you would need to write some SQL code to select the LastLoginDate stored in the database.

Comment: ok. I will write ado.net code. Thank you.